# certbot and redis tls: which files I need to use?

Tags: ssl, redis, openssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to setup TLS with a self-hosted redis server.

I've installed certbot on my server and ran the following command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone
```

This generated the following files:

```
chain.pem
fullchain.pem
privkey.pem
cert.pem
```

I followed the information [posted here](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/encryption/) and I edited the following settings in my redis.conf-file:

```
port 0
tls-port 6379
tls-cert-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
tls-key-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem
tls-ca-cert-file /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/cert.pem
```

This doesn't work, the redis.service won't restart and gives an error.

I probably have the wrong files in my config. Can someone help me out which certificate-files I need to use?

**Edit:** when running `/usr/bin/redis /etc/redis/redis.conf` directly, everything works. Seems there is some problem with the redis.service.

Comment: Why are you not following the redis manual symbol by symbol? Why do you run `certbot` without a `-d`? 

Comment: what do you mean? I have added my domain to certbot, the -d flag is optional, it asks for the domain if you don't use it

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that.  In my LetsEncrypt configuration the `fullchain.pem` is called `chain.pem`, the `ca`. `cert` is `cert`. 